# Find child object with certain key value using lodash

Tags: lodash

I want to use lodash to go through an object of objects to find an object with a certain id value. the object has the following structure:

```
const a = {

  "11": {
    "id": 11,
  },
  "12": {
    "id": 12,
  },
}
```

lodash

```
findKey(a, ["id", 12])
```

Comment: `_.findKey(a, {id: 12})` or just `a[12]` if the key is always the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

**ES5**

var object = _.find(a,{id:12})

**ES6**

const object = _.find(a,{12})

More info at [Lodash Docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#find)